# ZMQ cross compile for Beagelbone black Angstrom

Tags: cross-compiling, zeromq, beagleboneblack

Has anyone succesfully cross compiled Zmq for beaglebone black running in angstrom?
Is there any resources that can be reffered for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative approach**

You can use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) instead of Angstrom. Perform following steps:

```
git clone git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
cd buildroot
make beaglebone_defconfig
make menuconfig
```

Select `zeromq` package.

```
make
```

You'll find your `rootfs` image under `output/images`.